# Tuples inside Tuples type different or similar?

Tags: haskell

Is `[([(True, False),(True, False)])]` equivalent to `[((True, False),(True, False))]` in terms of typing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**. We can query the type in GHCi, and obtain:

```
Prelude> :t [([(True, False),(True, False)])]
[([(True, False),(True, False)])] :: [[(Bool, Bool)]]
Prelude> :t [((True, False),(True, False))]
[((True, False),(True, False))] :: [((Bool, Bool), (Bool, Bool))]
```

So the first expression is a list of lists of 2-tuples of `Bool`s; the latter is a list of 2-tuples of 2-tuples of `Bool`s.

A list is *not* a tuple. In Haskell in a list *all* elements have the *same* type, furthermore the *length* of the list is not fixed at *compile* time.

A tuple on the other hand has a *fixed* arity (number of elements), and the type of the elements can vary.

We can also see that in the syntax: `(True, False)` is a 2-tuple with two booleans, but in the first variant, we put this expression twice between *square* brackets (hence a list), whereas in the latter, it is between *round* brackets (hence a tuple, or brackets to "group" an expression).